# Translate blazor server site with .NET 7

Tags: c#, translation, blazor-server-side, resx, asp.net-core-localization

I try to find a way to translate a site that is writen with C# Blazor Server .NET 7.

It seems that there is no clear solution.

In the official page there is a solution with MVC although it refers to Blazor Server.

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server)

I would like to use a dropdown to select the language for example

something like this

```
<select class="form-control"  style="width:300px; margin-left:10px;">
@foreach (var culture in cultures)
{
    <option value="@culture"onclick="@(()=>OnLangSelected(culture))">@culture.DisplayName</option>
}
</select>
@code{
string[] cultures = new[]
{
    "en",
    "el"
};
protected async Task OnLangSelected(string selLang)
  {
    var cult = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).First(c => c.Name == selLang);
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture=cult;
  }
}
```

In program.cs I use

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStringLocalizer<Index>, StringLocalizer<Index>>();
```

And I created a Resources folder where I have 2 files Index.el.resx and Index.en.resx

In Index.razor I use

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<Index> L
....
@L["varNameOfResx"]
```

But I get as a result varNameOfResx and not the translation in either language english or greek.

What am I doing wrong?
Could you provide any help?

Comment: Two quotes cannot be nested. Try  `<option value="@culture" @onclick='@(()=>OnLangSelected("en"))'>@culture.DisplayName</option>`

Comment: This is not the problem. I edited the code in my example.
The problem is that probably it doesn't find the  Name "varNameOfResx" in resx files or it does not has access to resx files.
Something in Program.cs or in the place that .resx files should be put

Comment: Try configure the path to the file correctly, "https://egvijayanand.in/2021/08/20/net-maui-manage-app-resources/"